# How to check what site mode you are using in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, trusted-sites

How can I check what site type a page is using, when browsing in Chrome? I know how to add something to the "Trusted Site", etc, but how can I check if it is applying correctly?

Specifically, I want to check that a page I am using is listed as "Intranet Zone", but I cannot find a way to verify that this is applying correctly within Chrome itself.

- Windows 7, All Updates
- Chrome Latest Version